# Remove element from one list based on elements in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have Two lists like this:

```
options = [['64', '32', '42', '16'], ['Sit', 'Beg', 'Shake', 'Catch'], ['Lion', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Puppy']]
right_answer = ['42', 'Sit', 'Puppy']
```

I want to remove the right_answer from options and get an output like this:

```
incorrect_answer = [['64', '32', '16'], ['Beg', 'Shake', 'Catch'], ['Lion', 'Dog', 'Cat']]
```

I tried using .remove() but it clears the list:

```
for i in range(0,len(options)):
   incorrect_answers = options[i].remove(right_answer[i])
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple list comprehension with `zip` that doesn't mutate the original lists

```py
incorrect_answers = [[answer for answer in possible if answer != correct] for possible, correct in zip(options, right_answer)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU89C8IwFNzzK55TLGTRlm5d1NFB6FiC1BLbh5KEJCL1z1fTvoDi8j7u3V0udgyD0fk0GRvQaA8VNA0vCy6A59tYi7luSi4FNLzGENed6mOrh/am4rBvQzcsjOPHJkIH09MlttPD2pFLyRz2Qzi32j@Vi4@RP/kSjTHUnXFOdYm6BCPZ1TigETVY4z1e7grwmtBVBSSXMzlRRIKj7oV2Tb8W8B0rk8w61CFdM1p/OIT95cym6Q0)

Answer (score 1):

you can use zip:

```
for o, r in zip(options, right_answer):
    o.remove(r)
    
print(options)
```

Comment: i need the output in a new list instead of modifying options

Comment: @PushpeshKumar You said multiple times that you want to "remove". Creating a new list isn't "removing".

Answer (score 0):

```
options = [['64', '32', '42', '16'], ['Sit', 'Beg', 'Shake', 'Catch'], ['Lion', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Puppy']]
right_answer = ['42', 'Sit', 'Puppy']

print([[e for e in opt if e not in right_answer] for opt in options])
```

Result:

```
[['64', '32', '16'], ['Beg', 'Shake', 'Catch'], ['Lion', 'Dog', 'Cat']]
```

Comment: This has the potential downfall of producing the wrong result if there are questions where they have the same strings as possible answers, since you're just checking if it's in the list and not caring about order

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple loop with list comprehension to retain elements not in the right answers.

```
incorrect_answers = []
for i, my_list in enumerate(options):
    incorrect_answers.append([x for x in my_list if x != right_answer[i]])

print(incorrect_answers)
# [['64', '32', '16'], ['Beg', 'Shake', 'Catch'], ['Lion', 'Dog', 'Cat']]
```

Comment: This has the potential downfall of producing the wrong result if there are questions where they have the same strings as possible answers, since you're just checking if it's in the list and not caring about order

Comment: @Samathingamajig Yes, you are right. To deal with that issue, maybe we can change the codes slightly like this: `for i, my_list in enumerate(options):` `incorrect_answers.append([x for x in my_list if x != right_answer[i]])`